# Magento Billing Information

Tags: magento-1.9, email, billing-address, guest-checkout

What is the best way to go about removing unnecessary fields during the billing process as Guest? How i can Removing mandatory validation of **email field** in Guest checkout Case

Answer (score 0):

Find below mentioned file If they are not already exist within your theme copy the following files from the **base/default** theme to your theme:

```
template/customer/address/edit.phtml
template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

**For example remove validation on city field :**

In each of these files, look for the `<input>` that defines the **city** field and remove the required class from the label, remove the required-attribute class from the input and make sure to remove the *.

In the same way you can remove others field validation or comment `<input>` for completely disable this fields.

I hope you will get some idea from this.

Comment: i do this steps but if checkout as Guest in billing Information i got an alert message `Email is a required value.` any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Find below mentioned file If they are not already exist within your theme copy the following files from the base/default theme to your theme:

**--1--**

**from->**

```
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
```

**to->**

```
app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
```

**and change the code below -->**

```
if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getEmail(), 'EmailAddress')) {
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Invalid email address "%s".', $this->getEmail());
        }
```

**to -->**

```
if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getEmail(), 'EmailAddress') && Zend_Validate::is( trim($this->getEmail()) , 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Invalid email address "%s".', $this->getEmail());
        }
```

**--2--**

If you're working with a **Community Edition**, you'll have to **manually change this value with SQL**. It's in `eav_attribute` table, the attribute_code is `email` and you just need to set `is_required` to `0`.

**or using Query SQL** `UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code = 'email';`